# Google Sheets COUNT/FILTER function

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, countif

I'm having some trouble getting these functions to work. I'm not even sure if they're the ones that I should be using, but here is the following information I can provide. I had previously opened a topic, but I was getting responses about my confusing query. So, hopefully this one is better explained.

I have data in the following fields: A1:N7, as well as A12:L18.
I need a function to check all of the fields and add up the amount of times certain numbers show up. The numbers that need to be checked are: `<90`, `90-99.99`, `100-109.99`, and `=>100`.

First off, I can use this formula to count the <90 and =>100 values in all the fields, which works.

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:N7,"<90")
```

However, I'm unsure how to appropriately add the results from `A12:L18` into it. My attempts have failed. Likewise, for the ranged functions, I'm completely lost. I've tried something like this:

```
=COUNT(FILTER(A1:N7,A1:N7>=90,A1:N7<=99.99))
```

Yet, this always returns `0` as the result. In addition, like the above formula I don't know how I'd nest in a way to check the additional fields in `A12:L18`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want:

```
={"<90",COUNTIF({A1:N7;A12:N18},"<90");"90-99.99",COUNTIFS({A1:N7;A12:N18},">=90",{A1:N7;A12:N18},"<100");"100-109.99",COUNTIFS({A1:N7;A12:N18},">=100",{A1:N7;A12:N18},"<110");"=>110",COUNTIF({A1:N7;A12:N18},">=110")}
```

I made an example sheet where you can see it working: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BPexh5syksapZ9rd_brAa3NkN28LXAvB6dVMLEkM2r0/edit#gid=0

Comment: This seems perfect, but it doesn't work. Will it not work if all my numbers that it's trying to count are decimal's? The formula is returning every result as 0.

Comment: I don't think decimals should be a problem as they are still numerical values.  The zero result could indicate that the values are formatted as text  though - can you confirm this via the Format menu or by using an ISNUMBER formula?

Comment: If I format everything to Plain Text, it doesn't change anything. In addition, if I add an ISNUMBER function, it changes the actual number to a TRUE/FASLE statement, which also doesn't change the 0 return on the formula.

Comment: Hrmmm, alright so I made a completely new sheet and input the same data. It worked. So there is something on the previous sheet that is killing the function somehow. The formula DOES work.

Answer (score 9):

An old thread, but I came across it trying to solve a similar problem.

Using the original example:

=COUNT(FILTER(A1:N7,A1:N7>=90,A1:N7<=99.99))

I was also getting zero until I realised COUNT returns the number of NUMERIC values in the range.  Assuming the result range isn't numeric, I tried:

=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:N7,A1:N7>=90,A1:N7<=99.99))

and got the result I was expecting.

Comment: Also, if your `FILTER` returns an empty list, `COUNTA` will count N/A as a value and the result of the formula will be `1`. To prevent this, you can wrap `FILTER` with `IFERROR`. In this case, if `FILTER` returns an empty list `COUNTA` will return 0.

Answer (score 7):

You just need count rows your matrix with ROWS()

```
=ROWS(FILTER(...))
```